# OpenCV detect the outermost edges C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I have an application where I have to detect the first occurrence of edges in a particular direction ( light to dark or inverse ).

Suppose I have this input image ( arrows representing the direction of edges )

[image]

I want to detect the edge line ( in green color in the following image )

[image]

I've read about canny, sobel edge detectors. But I have no idea how to detect just the first edge. Also I would like to know is there a way we can specify the polarity of the edge ( like light to dark color, or dark to light ) so it ignores the others ?

Sorry for no code, I just have no clue where to start.

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: So those drawing rectangles will always be in your samples?

Comment: The black item the edge of which I'm trying to detect may or might not be present. I need to detect it's presence and further calculate something based on it's position if it's present.

Comment: I meant blue color rectangle, ll be in there always? Also the arrows?

Comment: No. The arrows are just to demonstrate what I want. The blue rectangle is the region I select in my application. I will crop this region and try to detect within this smaller image.

Comment: If arrows will not be there, can you share the pure image to work on it. And also you said that "if its present..."  so it can be good also to share a negative image where your object is not present .

Comment: here https://drive.google.com/open?id=14eI1ORFNtqzj2fQl1siEIhKRg0LlmBHF

Comment: For the moment I have voted to close your question because it is unclear what you are really trying to do. Please try to improve your question and I will retract the close vote. It is very unclear what is part of your image and what is your marking-up to show what you are looking for. Your link also points to a folder of 10 images and there is no indication of which one we should be looking at, or what they show or why you have cropped them the way you have.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry. I've updated the link items and added a readme file.